# Can we write into physical address linux

Tags: linux, operating-system

In linux,Is there a way to write data directly into a physical address(say 0x777777)?
Can we create a virtual address for a specific physical address( 0x777777)

Edit:
PS: I am not going to try doing this. This is just to clarify my understanding

Comment: Why would you want to do that? To cause a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will cause a SIGSEGV. To accomplish that, you have to use a system specific function to map the region of memory that contains this exact address before trying to access it.

Anyways, you better know what you are doing this, but you can use

```
*(int*)0x7777777 = 2345
```

Mapping to physical location is already taken care by OS.

Comment: thanks for your answer. When you do this "*(int*)0x7777777 = 2345" it means 0x7777777  is a virtual address right. and that will be mapped to some random physical address.?

Comment: 0x77777 is the physical address. so before writing this in your code, be sure what you are doing.